# Understanding ? and ! in swift - Specific case

Tags: ios, swift, option-type, unwrap

I am begining with swift and iOS and I have crashed against a doubt. Let see, having this particular source code:

```
if object?.stringValue != nil {
    // send it to server
    session.stopRunning()
    sendQRCodeToApiServer(stringValueObtained: (object?.stringValue)!)
}
```

I understand that in `if object?.stringValue != nil` the ? character means that object var could be nil, so it is an optional. But in the internal line:

```
sendQRCodeToApiServer(stringValueObtained: (object?.stringValue)!)
```

The interpreter throws an error if I don't unwrap the object?.stringValue in () and with a exclamation mark (!), that (if I had understood perfect) means that you are sure that the result have a value and it has the type required, I mean, the object.stringValue has a value and IT IS a string.

Well, I understand this perfect, but the compiler says that ? and ! are required, first says that maybe has a value and second that is sure that has a value, ........

I see this syntax incongruent and confusing, can anyone explain me?

Thanks a lot for your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Optionality / force unwrapping / optional chaining can be very confusing.

As a rule of thumb if you are finding that you have to force unwrap variables 'unexpectedly' then it is absolutely worth revisiting the code to deliberately unwrap variables you wish to access.

Some might say "***Every time you use an ! , a baby unicorn dies (horribly)***"

In your first line of code, object is an optional

```
if object?.stringValue != nil {
```

unless you specifically unwrap object you have to use the ? notation whenever you access it or it's members. Thats why when you access it again later inside the method call to **sendQRCodeToApiServer**, you have to unwrap it again.

When you unwrap an optional, the name you give to the unwrapped version of the variable works just like any other variable in that scope. Also when you unwrap an optional bear in mind that you are actively reducing the number of ? and ! that appear in your code so you are really making it much more readable and understandable for yourself in 6 months time or the next developer that sees your code (Hey and the unicorns love you).

Let's unwrap specifically the only variable you wish to use (if you had many lines of code that access object members then we could unwrap object - but let's stick with your code example)

```
if let stringValueObtained = object?.stringValue {
    // send it to server
    session.stopRunning()
    sendQRCodeToApiServer(stringValueObtained: stringValueObtained)
}
```

Note:

- Outside of the scope of the if statement **stringValueObtained** does not exist
- I specifically have named the unwrapped variable for it's intended use

Comment: Lets check if I could understand you. In my example, in the first line abject is an optional, and could be nil, neither stringValue can be nil. In the second statement object remains being an optional, but we are sure that is not a nil, so using ! we unwrap the optional to ensure the compilar thats a string value. As you said is not a good practice, your example is much better than mine, and obviously it is easier to understand. More logical than mine, I mean. Well, if I am right, THANKS A LOT FOR YOUR KNOWLEDGE

Answer (score 3):

The syntax force-unwraps an optional chained expression `object?.stringValue`. As you can't write `object?.stringValue!` because the result of `stringValue` is not an optional you have add the parentheses `(object?.stringValue)!`

Unfortunately the compiler suggests that syntax although it's practically exactly the same as `object!.stringValue` which is perfectly fine in your case as `object` is definitely not `nil` after the check.

Answer (score 1):

use it with optional binding with 'if let'

```
if let stringVal = object?.stringValue {
    // send it to server
    session.stopRunning()
    sendQRCodeToApiServer(stringValueObtained: stringVal)
}
```

Always when you use optional chaining , then use if let binding because optional chaining always return an optional value ,whether the declaration of that value container means object is non optional.

Answer (score 1):

```
 sendQRCodeToApiServer(stringValueObtained: (object?.stringValue)!)
```

In this line the compiler prompts you to unwrap because the function "stringValueObtained" needs a non-nill value as an argument. If you change the parameter of the function as optional it won't prompt you to unwrap.
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

First, let inspect this:

```
if object?.stringValue != nil {
```

If object is nil or stringValue is nil, the condition will be false. That's objects?.whatEver will return nil if object is nil, and object?.stringValue will return nil if stringValue is nil.

```
sendQRCodeToApiServer(stringValueObtained: (object?.stringValue)!)
```

`sendQRCodeToApiServer` require a String, but `object?.stringValue` return a `String?` so you need to unwrap. Because of the if condition, so it's safe to unwrap here. Either by object!.stringValue (unwrap object) or (object?.stringValue)! - unwrap the returned value.

The better option is unwrap in if condition:

```
if let stringVal = object?.stringValue {
    // send it to server
    session.stopRunning()
    sendQRCodeToApiServer(stringValueObtained: stringVal)
}
```

Comment: Is not my idea to do this as I wrote, It is a fix from Xcode compilator.

Answer (score 0):

`if object?.stringValue != nil` is only checked not nil.
So, you need to unwrapping value.
Recommand to use this code.

`if let stringValue = object?.stringValue {
    session.stopRunning()
    sendQRCodeToApiServer(stringValueObtained: stringValue)
}`

Comment: I wrote this exactly like you, and the compiler throws an error and fix as I posted